# import asp.net / ms sql 2012 website database to local mysql server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012-express

I have website developed in asp.net and used MS SQL Server 2012 for database, my task to make website responsive, I have decided make changes loacaly first, I have downloaded whole source through ftp, and downloaded database backup from control panel. My problem is that when I try to restore dowloaded db back up file   , it keeps showing me error message "No backupset selected to be restored", please check attached screen. I am new to ASP.NET / MS SQL Server 2012, can any one help me to solve this issue ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your backup file is invalid. It should be ended with .bak suffix. Just choose the suitable file and remember to check the date of this file!
Hope this can help!

Comment: it's file i downloaded from control panel of website, and its fully downloaded, and there was no '.bak' suffix when i download

Comment: May be you should add the .bak for this file and try it

Comment: Backup file can be created without .bak extension, so there is not a reason to fail. May be original SQL2012 has some SP installed while local SQL Server doesn't have it. Can you check?

Comment: i downloaded sql server 2014 express studio and try to restore my database backup.  samething happening